# Insert functional React component into string HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

OK so I'm getting valid html from the database and want to find and replace merge tags with functional react components. The HTML is created within a WYSIWYG editor.

For example

```
const link = <a onClick={()=>alert('clicked')}>Click me</a>  
const html = "<p>Html taken from the server{{react_component_here}}</p>"  
//now need to convert html into JSX and then find and replace"{{react_component_here}}" with link component`
```

The html might be several tags deep and there might be several merge tags in the template downloaded from the server.

I've tried using dangerouslySetInnerHtml and running the find and replace on there using the react-string-replace but it just parses [object:Object] in to the output.

I can parse static html in to the source html no problem, but the component that's inserted needs to be functional with state and click bindings etc.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you need to show the HTML code from DB? Where does the component come from?

Comment: @TheKNVB I want to display the html with the functional component. The functional component is derived from the script and inserted with variables etc

Comment: UPDATE: I've useed html-react-parser to convert in to JSX and then react-string-replace does exactly what I want it to, but only on the first level of components. It wont look to see if the component has children. I'm guessing a but of magic to loop through an indefinite number of levels is needed

Comment: Would you post your component source code? Do you mean you need to pass the HTML code to the child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so for other people seeing this I used html-react-parser which has a handy replace function

```
outputHtml = parse(contractHtml,{
                replace: domNode => {
                    if (typeof domNode.data == 'string' && domNode.data.includes('{{signature_')) {
                        let id = domNode.data.replace('{{signature_','')
                        let match = id.replace('}}','')
                        const sig = signatures.find(o=>o.id == match)
                        console.log(match,'matched to ',sig)
                        return <Signature {...sig} handleChange={(data)=>_setSignature(data)} />
                    } 
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `React-JSX-Parser`**

You can use the React-JSX-Parser library to parse string and JSX elements

`npm install react-jsx-parser`

see the [DOCS](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser) for more info

react-jsx-parser has a replace function that can be passed as the second argument. I regex matched my search string and replaced it with the functional component.